# Filter and update data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{
    "_id": "5c0a17013d8ca91bf4ee7885",
    "fixed": [
      {
        "from": "1970-01-01",
        "to": "1970-01-02",
        "isCompleted": true
      },
      {
        "from": "2017-04-18",
        "to": "2017-04-23",
        "isCompleted": false
      },
      {
        "from": "2018-01-29",
        "to": "2018-01-30",
        "isCompleted": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c0a17013d8ca91bf4ee7886",
    "fixed": [
      {
        "from": "1970-01-01",
        "to": "1970-01-02",
        "isCompleted": true
      },
      {
        "from": "2017-04-18",
        "to": "2017-04-23",
        "isCompleted": false
      },
      {
        "from": "2018-01-29",
        "to": "2018-01-30",
        "isCompleted": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c0a17013d8ca91bf4ee7887",
    "fixed": [
      {
        "from": "2019-04-15",
        "to": "2019-04-25",
        "isCompleted": false
      },
      {
        "from": "2017-04-18",
        "to": "2017-04-23",
        "isCompleted": false
      },
      {
        "from": "2018-01-29",
        "to": "2018-01-30",
        "isCompleted": false
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have this type of data in my db and I want to update isCompleted to false. with filter using date like this:

```
find({
  fix: {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        from: {
          $lt: "1970-01-02"
        },
        to: {
          $gt: "1970-01-01"
        },
        "isCompleted": true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

with this query I got the object but how can I set isCompleted to false with give date like here is 1970-01-01 and 1970-01-02

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/WIoZZ5k0Myu

Comment: `find` query only returns the documents. You have to use `update` query to update the data.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Can you please help me with that query?

Comment: Please try to explain what exactly do you need

Comment: Let say I have three data in my collection, and I want to findandupdate isComplated status based on dates that i pass in a query. Like if i pass from and to date then I got one document as a response now  I want to change status of isCompleted on that document that I got as a response. So How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

findAndModify could solve your problem. Below is just a pseudocode.

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
    query: {  from: {$lt: "1970-01-02"}  },
    update: { isCompleted: true },
    upsert: true
})
```